# netstat localhost and ifconfig ip address

Tags: linux

I am running a web server on my local machine. If I reference the page using "localhost" I can retrieve the page. However, if I use my ip address instead, I get a 404.

I got my ip address from ifconfig:

`eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fc:aa:14:86:fa:7d

          inet addr:10.3.1.189  Bcast:10.3.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::feaa:14ff:fe86:fa7d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:164372 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:63584 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:68190717 (68.1 MB)  TX bytes:15708817 (15.7 MB)`

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:21861 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:21861 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:2552283 (2.5 MB)  TX bytes:2552283 (2.5 MB)

my netstat, grepping for the port is

```
dev@c1:~/tempdel$ netstat -atn | grep 63342
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:63342         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

so, if I try `http://localhost:63342/test`, it works, but if I try `http://10.3.1.189:63342/test` I get an error (`Connecting to 10.3.1.189:63342... failed: Connection refused.`
).

Why can't I open the file with my 10.3.1.189 address, but I can with 127.0.0.1?

Comment: This belongs on another site like ServerFault, its not really on topic for NE.

Answer (score 2):

A 404 is an application specific error/response code which means immediately this is not a networking issue.  A networking issue would be a timeout or a reset or some sort of error like this.

This means the first place to look is your web server logs.  Especially anything related to virtual hosts or listeners.  You want to make sure the ip 10.3.1.189 is registered to your application.

Comment: Thanks, jhenn. I was getting the error on my browser, which gave me a different error. When I do a wget on the address I get a different error: Connecting to 10.3.1.189:63342... failed: Connection refused.
I've updated my question.

Answer (score 2):

Your webserver isn't listening on 10.3.1.189, only on 127.0.0.1. The solution (which probably is off topic here) is to fix the webserver configuration so it's listening on that IP address.

Comment: huh. I thought that 127.0.0.1 was just an alias for whatever ip had been assigned to you.

Comment: No. **127.0.0.1** is a *specific* address. *0.0.0.0* is "any address" (aka INADDR_ANY)